# Нужна ли запятая после "делать-то"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Полностью согласен, а делать-то что теперь будем?*

*Делать-то что теперь будем, маг?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне эти предложения видятся по-другому ("что" не может быть подлежащим).
В первом предложении первая часть повествовательная (с утвердительной интонацией), вторая часть — вопросительная. Между собой они никак не связаны.

Без всякого ущерба для смысла можно написать так:
**Полностью согласен. А делать-то** [мы] **что теперь будем?**

Подлежащее **мы** пропущено, **а** — частица, предложение вопросительное (нормальная конфигурация: *А что* [мы] *теперь делать-то будем?*) — **что** является вопросительным местоимением. Никаких запятых не нужно.

Во втором предложении все то же самое.
**Делать-то что** [мы] **теперь будем, маг?** = ***Что*** [мы] теперь делать-то будем, маг?

[Какая часть речи слово «что»?](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/kakaya-chast-rechi/slovo-chto.html)

Answer (score 1):

Нет конечно, ни в коем случае! *"Что"* здесь местоимение, а не союз придаточного предложения. Если переставить слова *что* и *делать-то,* запятую совсем негде будет ставить, поэтому она не нужна и при исходном порядке слов. Кроме того, если бы запятая была нужна, слова бы не удалось легко переставить местами.